# Node.js / Inheritance of variables and modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I have trouble with inheritance in node.js. I have the following code:

Main.js relavnt code:

```
var s3_prototype_require = require("./s3")
var s3_prototype = new s3_prototype_require();

function getDoc(file) {
        s3_prototype.read(file, function(err) {
            return_result(res, err);
        })
     }
```

server,js relvant code:

```
var server = function(){};
var idx = 0;    
var winston = require('winston')
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            stream: fs.createWriteStream(log_g, {
                flags: 'a'
            }),
            options: {
                highWaterMark: 32
            }
        })
    ]
});

module.exports = server;
```

s3.js relvant code:

```
var server= require('./server'),
util = require('util');

var s3 = function() {
  this.s3 = 's3';
};

util.inherits(server, s3);

s3.prototype.read = function(file, callBack) {
     logger.info("Read file...");
     idx = idx + 1;     
}
```

The problem is that I failed on the following error: `ReferenceError: logger is not defined`. This is despide the fact I defined the logger variable in the server.js code. Similar problem happens with the `idx` variable.

How I define variable and modules Inheritance in node.js (like protected in Java)?

Comment: This is not how node modules work. The only existent value is the value that is assigned to the `module.exports`. Those variables are not defined in the other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I define variable and modules Inheritance in node.js (like protected in Java)?

Objects in JavaScript are a little different from your traditional objects in languages like Java. Objects can't really have *protected* values, but you can have inheritance by utilizing [prototypes through prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). With your particular problem, you just need to define your `server` variable with its respective properties so that they can be initialized when you create instances of your object.

The problem lies with your `server.js`. You define `logger`, along with some other variables, locally within that file, but you only export the `server` variable, which is unrelated to these other variables.

```
// You're only exporting this function
var server = function(){};

// These are not being exported and just live within this file.
var idx = 0;    
var winston = require('winston')
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            stream: fs.createWriteStream(log_g, {
                flags: 'a'
            }),
            options: {
                highWaterMark: 32
            }
        })
    ]
});

module.exports = server;
```

To fix this, try assigning your `server` object these variables as properties.

Maybe something like this (I cant't test it so there may be some tweaking that needs to be done)

```
var server = function(){
    this.idx = 0;
    this.winston = require('winston');
    this.logger = new(winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new(winston.transports.File)({
                stream: fs.createWriteStream(log_g, {
                    flags: 'a'
                }),
                options: {
                    highWaterMark: 32
                }
            })
        ]
    });
};

module.exports = server;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to export an object.

server.js

```
module.exports = {
  server: server,
  logger: logger
};
```

s3.js

```
var serverObj = require('./server');
var server = serverObj.server;
var logger = serverObj.logger;
```

However I suggest moving the logger related code to it's own file for the sake of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

```
var server = require('./server');
var logger = require('./logger');
```

Comment: Thanks. what about the idx variable? How to export it so it will be common to all classes?

Comment: @MiddleWare you can export a setter and getter for idx